# for loop is initialising with three variables

Tags: c, for-loop

I have a doubt that why 3 variables   wstart = wend = start; are used to initialise the loop.if the value of any of these variable changes will it change the value of both variable ???

```
void reverseletter(char str[], int start, int end) {               
    int wstart, wend; 
    for (wstart = wend = start; wend < end; wend++) { 

        if (str[wend] == ' ') 
            continue; 

        // Checking the number of words 
        // present in string to reverse 
        while (str[wend] != ' ' && wend <= end) 
            wend++; 
        wend--; 

        //Reverse the letter 
        //of the words 
        reverse(str, wstart, wend); 
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`wstart = wend = start` is the same as

```
wend = start;
wstart = start;
```

> if the value of any of these variable changes will it change the value of both variable ?

No, changing one variable won't affect the others, all 3 are independent variables.

Comment: so in the next iteration when start will become 1 ,at that time the value of wend and wstart will change or not?????and why do we use such kind of method and how will i get to know where i have to use such kind of mehod

Comment: @AbdaalAhmad No. `wend` and `wstart` won't change when `start` changes. If it helps, you can rewrite `for (wstart = wend = start; wend < end; wend++)` to `wend = start; wstart = start; for (; wend < end; wend++)` or `wstart = start; for (wend = start; wend < end; wend++)`. You use it when you need to. If it's too confusing then resort to using multiple single assignments.

Answer (score 1):

An assignement like `b = c` is itself an expression whose value is the value of `b` after the assignment.

Therefore

```
a = b = c;
```

can be seen as

```
a = (b = c);
```

which is equivalent to:

```
b = c;
a = b;
```

All three variables a,b and c stay totally independent of each other.

You can demonstrate this with following snippet:

```
int a = 1;
int b = 2;
printf("%d\n", a);
printf("%d\n", a = b);
printf("%d\n", a);
```

Output

```
1
2
2
```

Comment: Re “An [assignment] like `b = c` is itself an expression whose value is c.”: Not quite. The value of the assignment is the value `b` has after assignment, which is the value of `c` converted to the type of `b`. For example, given `int b`, the value of `b = 3.5` is 3, not 3.5. And, if we had `float a; int b; float c; c = 3.5; a = b = c;`, it would be equivalent to `a = (int) c; b = c;`, not `a = c; b = c;`.

Comment: @EricPostpischil yes, thanks for the clarification, question edited

Answer (score 0):

If you change one of the variables, it will not change the other. All of them **do not** reference to the same memory location.

```
int wstart, wend; 
for (wstart = wend = start; wend < end; wend++) {
```

`wstart`, `wend` and `start`, each will have their copy of the values and changing one will not change others.

Answer (score 0):

This snippet

```
wstart = wend = start
```

takes advantage of the fact that, in C, assignment is an expression that returns a value. What happens is that `wend = start` assigns the value of `start` to `wend` and "returns" it. This "return" value is assigned to `wstart`. Thus the overall effect is to assign `start` to both `wend` and `wstart`.

It's a style I've seen before but I don't personally like it. I would prefer:

```
for (wstart = start, wend = start; wend < end; wend++)
```

which does the same thing but in a clearer way IMO.